# changing the button value on ng-click using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am having a list of item with me, which I displayed using **ng-repeat**.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat = "item in items">
      item-{{item}} <button ng-click = 'addThis(item)'>add to list</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

When the user click on the button **add to list** it will add the item to the another list. After adding that I want the button value to be **added to list**, and the button ng-click function should be removed.

*The controller*

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];
  $scope.addedItems = [];
  $scope.addThis=function(item){
    var added = false;
    for(var i=0;i<$scope.addedItems.length;i++){
        if($scope.addedItems[i] === item){
            added = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!added){
        $scope.addedItems.push(item);
        // here i want something to change the button
        console.log($scope.addedItems);
        }
    else{
        alert("already added");
        }       
   }
}
```

Can somebody please show me how to change the button value if the item is already added to the list.

I am attaching a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/muralicse/yf4gbhp5/) here.

Comment: You can use a directive for this.

Comment: See my answer below, it contains the _fiddle_ with the directive you need. It gives you a good start.

Comment: I guess that having a directive won't hurt, but I don't think that you need a directive at all for something that simple.

Comment: @Josep so, what's the best way to manipulate the DOM and replace the button text?

Comment: @denisazevedo to use directives, of course! But angular already provides you with a nice set of directives, why not use the already existing ones for something that simple? For something like this `ng-disabled` is the only directive that you need.

Comment: @Josep Oh, I see, sorry. Yeah, another good way to accomplish that. But definitely my answer doesn't deserve a downvote only because it uses "the most powerful feature of AngularJS". It's just another way to achieve that.

Comment: @denisazevedo I won't down-vote your answer, of course not.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple directive for this and then use:

```
 <button my-button ng-click = 'addThis(item)'>add to list</button>
```

Here is your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yf4gbhp5/3/).

You can easily disable, do whatever you want with your element.

The directive is the AngularJS solution for DOM manipulation.

For more: [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/#!/guide/directive).

Comment: I won't down-vote this answer, but this is not doing what the OP has asked for. Also, why not just use the already existing directives? For solving this you only need to use the `ng-disabled` directive and a ternary operator for the inner html of the `button`. Sure, you could create a custom directive too, but don't you think that's an overkill?

Comment: @Josep I completely agree, but the OP wants to change the button value, not only disable it: "After adding that I want the button value to be added to list"

Comment: so? Have a look at the first example of my answer. You can do that with a ternary operator ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sample

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat = "item in items">
    item-{{item}} <button ng-hide="buttonHidden[$index]" ng-click = 'addThis(item, $index)'>add to list</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then After adding,

```
$scope.addedItems.push(item);
$scope.buttonHidden[$index] = true;
```